# Vue3 reactivity of an "external" array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

While porting an existing app from Vue2 to Vue3 I faced a surprising problem.

How can I make Vue3 watch an "external" array for changes?

**This worked perfectly fine in Vue2, but stopped working in Vue3:**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li v-for="t in dataArray"> {{t}} </li>
</ul>

<script>
    var numbers = [1,2,3]; //this is my external array

    var app = Vue.createApp({
        data() { return { dataArray : numbers } } //bind Vue to my external array
    }).mount("#list");

    numbers.push(4); //UI not updating, but worked fine in Vue2

</script>
```

I know I can call `app.dataArray.push` instead, or call `$forceUpdate`, etc. but is there a way to force Vue to simply monitor an existing array?

I guess the broader question is: how to bind Vue3 to an arbitrary plain-JS object? The object can be too complex to rewrite or can come from an external API that I don't control. This is trivial in Vue2 or Angular (two-way binding with any plain object, whether or not it's part of the instance/component)

P.S. This looks like a huge breaking change in Vue3 that is not mentioned anywhere at all.

**UPDATE:**

According to a @Dimava's answer it looks looks like the least painful way of fixing the above code is this:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3]; //this is my external array
numbers = Vue.shallowReactive(numbers); //convert to a reactive proxy
```

Comment: This isn't a breaking change because it's a hacky way to do things that never was suggested in official docs and relies on internal V2 mechanisms. A proper way would be to have public method on app and modify data imperatively, or keep it in detached global reactive objects aka stores. It's what the answer says, yes, you'll have to stick to V2 to keep it working as is. FWIW, this isn't so in Angular too, both 1 and higher, you'd have to force update

Comment: @EstusFlask it's not a hacky way, and it WAS suggested in official VUE2 docs at https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to make your array `Reactive` ¹

```
import { reactive, ref } from 'vue'   
const numbers = [1,2,3];
const reactiveNumbers = reactive(numbers)
reactiveNumbers.push(4)

// or, if you will need to reassign the whole array
const numbersRef = ref(numbers)
numbersRef.value.push(4)
numbersRef.value = [3, 2, 1]

// or, in the old style, if you are old
const data = reactive({
  numbers: [1, 2, 3]
})
data.numbers.push(4)
data.numbers = [3, 2, 1]
```

¹ (or `ShallowReactive` if it contains a lot of big objects that shouldn't be reactive for performance reasons)

Comment: In other words: I can't bind Vue3 to an external object without rewriting all the code that modifies that object? Darn, I' guess I'm sticking with Vue2 then

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit you only need to rewrite the code where it's created, but well, yes